# Multiple Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I tried the following integration

$$\frac{1}{(2 \pi \hbar)^3} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp^3 exp[i\frac{\vec{p}\vec{r}}{\hbar}-i\frac{ip^2t}{2m\hbar}]$$

with this code but failed to have the right answer.

```
With[{r = {x, y, z}, p = {px, py, pz}}, 
 Integrate[1/(2 Pi h)^3 Exp[I (p.r) - I (p.p) t/(2 m h)], p \in Ball[]]]
```

Could anyone give me a hint? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What answer did you get? What did you expect? What is the syntax you are attempting with the use of `\in`? Do you also see that you have not properly closed up the `Exp`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They are typos when I edited in the Stacks (sorry about that), and \in means the mathematical symbol \in (I don't know how to type it in the code block). I can run the code in my Mathematica, but it just didn't give me a correct answer.

Comment: Do you mean `Sphere[]` (the shell) or `Ball[]` (the region within the sphere)

Comment: The answer should be : $$(\frac{m}{2\pi i \hbar t})^{3/2} \exp [i \frac{m}{2\hbar t} r^2], t\geq 0$$

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you. I should use Ball. But the result is still not right. It simply doesn't give me a explicit answer.

Comment: There is a mistake in your code, you must have "-" in front of $p^2$ because $i\times i =-1$.

Comment: Further, there is a syntax error: "\in" sould read "\[Element]". However, after some time  MMA returns the input. This could mean that no closed form of the integral exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this 1D integration

```
Assuming[Element[r, Reals] && t > 0 && m > 0 && h > 0,
 Integrate[
  1/(2 Pi h) Exp[I (p *r) - (p*p) t/(2 m h)], {p, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}]]
```

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{h m r^2}{2 t}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\frac{h t}{m}}}$$

The 3D integral factorizes into 3 such 1D integrals.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late acknowledgement.